# React hooks change the state on postMessage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component with some state using `useState`.

This component opens a new tab and should receive a message event on postMessage.
For some reason, after I get the event, the state returns to its initial state.

I tried saving the state to localStorage and it worked.

### index.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState("hello");

  const onClick = () => {
    setState("world");
    window.open("tab.html");
  };

  const onMessageReceivedFromIframe = event => {
    console.log("onMessageReceivedFromIframe", state, event);
  };

  const addIframeListener = () =>
    window.addEventListener("message", onMessageReceivedFromIframe);
  const removeIframeListener = () =>
    window.removeEventListener("message", onMessageReceivedFromIframe);

  useEffect(() => {
    addIframeListener();
    return () => {
      removeIframeListener();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Current state: ", state);
  }, [state]);

  return <button onClick={onClick}>Click here</button>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

### tab.html

```html
<html>
  <body>
    tab
    <script>
      setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("post");
      window.opener.postMessage("some message", "https://9jzj7.csb.app");
      window.close();
      }, 2000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The state returns to its initial state.

A demo can be seen here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-waterfall-9jzj7

BTW:
I know that the event is not fired from `tab.html` but there is still an event that fires on tab opening.

Answer (score 5):

seems your problem was with the deps array of your effect hook, and `onMessageReceivedFromIframe` being created on every render.
the solution below should work like you expect. here is a link to the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-cray-5euni?fontsize=14)

```
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState("hello");

  const onClick = () => {
    setState("world");
    console.log(state);
    window.open("tab.html");
  };

  const onMessageReceivedFromIframe = React.useCallback(
    event => {
      console.log("onMessageReceivedFromIframe", state, event);
    },
    [state]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("message", onMessageReceivedFromIframe);
    return () =>
      window.removeEventListener("message", onMessageReceivedFromIframe);
  }, [onMessageReceivedFromIframe]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("state", state);
  }, [state]);

  return <button onClick={onClick}>Click here</button>;
};
```

Comment: it will work for sure. just to add: it's not because `onMessageReceivedFromIframe` is create on each render but because author's code sets up only first instance of `onMessageReceivedFromIframe` as event listeners. so further updates generate new instance of `onMessageReceivedFromIframe` that points onto up-to-date data but it is not used anywhere.

Comment: so as alternative to `useCallback` they might use `useEffect` without deps specified so it will be run on each render with most recent `onMessageReceivedFromIframe` and everything would work as well

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the below code

```
useEffect(() => {
    addIframeListener();
    return () => {
      removeIframeListener();
    };
  }, []);
```

Since its calling `addIframeListener` and `removeIframeListener` from inside `effect` and the state `state` is getting used inside it.

Change the code as

```
useEffect(() => {
    addIframeListener();
    return () => {
      removeIframeListener();
    };
  }, [state]);
```

If there is any props getting used by `framelistener` function, keep that in dependent array otherwise you will end up getting old props

Comment: Only changing the useEffect didnt work. i had also use useCallback as mentioned above.